# Cant find the url for my custom build Yii2 API page

Tags: yii2

Still new to YII2, and im working on a already build YII2 project(learning on the spot) but I can't find the correct url/path to my newly added API page(s).
Not sure if there is something missing in the code, wrong paths or whatever.

If have tried:
(not working on localhost)

```
www.example.com/v1/product/
www.example.com/web/product
www.example.com/v1/product/web/product
```

...

**application structure**

```
+ api
  + config
    - main.php
 + modules
   + v1
     + controllers
       - ProductController.php
     + models
       - Product.php
     - RestModule.php
 + web
   - .htaccess
   - index.php
+ backend
+ common
+ frontend
```

**api/config/main.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\RestModule',
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
              'parsers' => [
                 'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
              ],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/product',
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

**api/modules/v1/controllers/ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

class ProductController extends yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\models\v1\models\Product';

    public function actionIndex(){

        echo 'product controller';

    }

}
```

**api/modules/v1/models/Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;

class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['description', 'name'], 'string']
        ];
    }
}
```

**api/modules/RestModule.php**

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1;

class RestModule extends \yii\base\Module
{

    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\modules\v1\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        echo 'restmodule';

    }

}
```

**api/web/index.php**

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
}

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

**api/web/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all
# Allow from 10.30.2.0/24
# Allow from 37.153.242.179

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ /img/blank.gif [L,R=302]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: check the answer if it helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Try `www.example.com/v1/products`.

> You may have noticed that the controller ID `user` appears in plural form as `users` in the endpoint URLs. This is because [`yii\rest\UrlRule`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule) automatically pluralizes controller IDs when creating child URL rules. You may disable this behavior by setting [`yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$pluralize-detail) to be `false`.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing

Comment: @user759235 You may try `www.example.com/products` or `www.example.com/api/web/products`, but it is hard to guess without knowing your webhost config.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    www.example.com/api/v1/product/
```

Comment: try adding index.php
like 
   www.example.com/index.php/api/v1/product/

Comment: 'v1' => [
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module',
        ]

replace RestModule by Module in your api/config/main.php file

Comment: also no response

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have the wrong namespace defined inside your controller for the `$modelClass` property it should be

```
public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Product';
```

rather than

```
public $modelClass = 'api\models\v1\models\Product';
```

you misspelled **`modules`** as **`models`** so change your controller to the following and remove the `actionIndex()`  from your controller

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

class ProductController extends yii\rest\ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Product';

}
```

`yii\rest\UrlRule` automatically pluralizes controller IDs and you can access it via **`www.example.com/v1/products`**, which will display all the records available in product table in `json` format because you are extending the `ActiveController`.

By default, `yii\rest\ActiveController` provides the following actions:

1. `index`: list resources page by page;
2. `view`: return the details of a specified resource;
3. `create`: create a new resource;
4. `update`: update an existing resource;
5. `delete`: delete the specified resource;
6. `options`: return the supported HTTP methods

Learn about [**`Extending ActiveController`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#extending-active-controller)

### About Creating Custom Actions

Yii provides two base controller classes to simplify your work of creating RESTful actions: **`yii\rest\Controller`** and **`yii\rest\ActiveController`**.

> The difference between these two controllers is that the latter
>   provides a default set of actions that are specifically designed to
>   deal with resources represented as Active Record. So if you are using
>   Active Record and are comfortable with the provided built-in actions,
>   you may consider extending your controller classes from
>   `yii\rest\ActiveController`, which will allow you to create powerful
>   RESTful APIs with minimal code.

Read More [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#controllers)

So if you intend to create your own actions you can create a controller that extends `yii\rest\Controller` or `yii\rest\ActiveController` see below controller try it with postman app or `curl` copy it to your `api\modules\v1\controllers` folder and call it with **`www.example.com/v1/basics/test`**.Also in order to use any custom action name that you use you should define the action inside the `extraPatterns` option for the `UrlRule` for example if you intend to create an action with the name `test` inside the `BasicController` which retrieves some information and response back, your rule should look like below

```
[
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule' ,
        'controller' => 'v1/basic' ,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'GET test' => 'test' ,
        ] ,
        'tokens' => [
            '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
        ]
    ]
```

Your controller will look like below

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;

class BasicController extends Controller {

    public function actionTest() {
        return "oho";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks the info(explains a lot), not seen the typo, sadly this will not make it work.

Comment: i just implemented an API today and in the same manner and it works great what doe not work did you followed every thing i said @user759235